# How run JavaScript with PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to run JavaScript code with PHP variables.

In the HTML it is OK. The script runs and the subpage is loaded within the content (div).

But when I try to run the script with PHP variables, it shows me only a subpage.

Original script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ex").click(function(event){
            $("#content").load('example.html');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

With PHP:

```php
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"<?php $link[1] ?>).click(function(event) {
            $("#content").load('<?php $link[0] ?>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where

```
<?php
    $links = array(
        $link = array('example.html', 'ex', 'Example')
    );

    foreach ($links as $value => $link)
    {
        echo '<li><a href=subpage/' . $link[0].id=' . $link[1] . '>' . $link[2] . '</a><li>';
    }
```

UPDATE:

When I use only JavaScript and HTML
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WsoN01_VlbQ3lWczZrbnh0TnM/view

When I use PHP variables and array of links
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WsoN01_Vlbc2VjVUVrWldIZ1U/view

Comment: You missed `echo`  `$("#"<?php $link[1] ?>`

Comment: I try script from @chandresh_cool script and doesn't work, also with echo

Comment: There is an error in the PHP echo line, "`echo '<li><a href=subpage/' . $link[0].id=' . $link[1] . '>' . $link[2] . '</a><li>';`". Near "`$link[0].id='`". This may or may not be the real reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#" + <?php echo $link[1] ?>).click(function(event){
        $("#content").load('<?php echo $link[0] ?>');
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work ;/ it open only page, but it should load page to content ;/

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the array properly here.

```
$links = Array(
   $link = array('example.html', 'ex', 'Example')
);
```

I think a single array is enough for this case. Do -

```
$links = array('example.html', 'ex', 'Example');
```

Then this should work -

```
$("#content").load('<?php echo $links[0] ?>');
```

**Update**

php -

```
echo '<li><a href=subpage/'.$link[0].' id='.$link[1].' class="ex-links">'.$link[2].'</a><li>';
```

js -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ex-links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it will work with more item in array? coz in array i have about 20 links.

Comment: <?php **echo** $links[0] ?>

Comment: You have to set the offset accordingly. You can use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(<?php echo '"#' . $link[1]'"'; ?>).click(function(event){
            $("#content").load(<?php echo "'" . $link[0]."'"; ?>);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Kindly see if it proceeds.

Comment: `$(<?php echo '"#'.$link[1].'"'; ?>).click(function(event){` forgot to add "." after "link[1]". kindly try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#<?php echo $link[1]; ?>").click(function(event){
            $("#content").load('<?php echo $link[0] ?>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

See that I fixed also the quotes in the first PHP echo.

Comment: also don't work. all time don't open page in content.

Comment: would you be so kind to show us what the javascript looks like when your page is displayed in browser? so that php is already parsed?

Comment: i have 2 panel on site. one with links, and area for showing content. and when i wrote all in php, without links in array it work fine, but when i use php variable it show me content in other page. problem is with loading to content for me but i don't know how improve that.

Comment: 1. what is the extension of the page? 2. where the php array is coming from? 3. can you show page source from browser (only the part related to the script thanks)!

Comment: this is index.php, i try paste code but stack doesn't allow me ;/ script is in head of page. i pasted to loop, to js file and all time is the same. when i click on link, it open in new page rather content in div.

Comment: @margaret just edit the question to add code or post here the link of the page please!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WsoN01_VlbSndIWkpoQ2VJbms/view?usp=sharing here is index.php, this is not published yet and stack doesn't allow me to post after editing ;/

Comment: this is your code from your editor. Show us what you see **in browser**. I still see <?php ?> code inside!

Comment: it should look like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WsoN01_VlbQ3lWczZrbnh0TnM/view?usp=sharing (result using only html and js)

Comment: using php variable: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1WsoN01_Vlbc2VjVUVrWldIZ1U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code contains errors, and it also produces a mixing up of the attributes of the hyperlink (href and id), a mix up of the jQuery selector, and in addition I am puzzled why the `a` tag should contain both a link in the href attribute and a load event on the onclick event.

This begs for the question: did you not check the output and or are you not familiar with how the syntax should be?

The relative complexity of what you are doing here, versus the obvious numerous errors in the output suggest for an advice that you really first should study proper syntax and check the output in a debugger (browser developer tools).

The below works fine with me. I assume your not trying to load a full HTML page in a div element. The href attribute could as well be empty or href="#" as it serves no purpose.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $links = Array(
                $link = array('content.txt', 'ex', 'Example')
            );

            foreach ($links as $value => $link)
            {
                echo "<li><a href='{$link[0]}' id='{$link[1]}'>{$link[2]}</a></li>";
            }
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#<?php echo $link[1] ?>").click(function(event){
                    $("#content").load('<?php echo $link[0] ?>');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep. i'm new with this ;/ and in netbeans i don't see errors 'coz it work, but not as i wanted.

Comment: I added some working tested code to the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach when you want to add **PHP in JavaScript** is to stack all the PHP information in an array then [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) to a mockup HTML element as per example.

**IMPORTANT:** Don't add sensitive information to `$phpInfo` because `#hold-php-data` will be visible under developerTools until JavaScript code is loaded and jQuery removes it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
      $phpInfo = array();

      $links = array(
        array('example.html', 'ex', 'Example'),
        array('example.html', 'ex', 'Example-2'),
      );

      // Add $links to $phpInfo

      if (!isset($phpInfo['links'])){
        $phpInfo['links'] = array();
      }

      $phpInfo['links'] = $links; // Now we have $links in our "global" variable
    ?>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script id="hold-php-data" data-php='<?php echo json_encode($phpInfo); ?>'></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {

        var mockupElement = $('#hold-php-data');

        // Get the JSON data from attribute and convert it to a valid object
        var phpInfo = JSON.parse(mockupElement.attr('data-php') || []);

        // We can safely remove the mockupElement since we have the
        // data so it won't be exposed to the user later on.
        mockupElement.remove();

        // Now you can access the links as phpInfo.links

        console.log('data from PHP', phpInfo);
      });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```